# Is there a way to forward define methods in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, forward-declaration

I am using an open source project where I can write code pieces in a GUI at several entry points and then it generates a complete python script with a class and appropriate methods. Entry points are:

- to add libraries imports
- to add code in the class _*init*_ method
- to add code in the so called *ConditionalRun* method which is executed periodically in an automation controller

I need to add methods to this class, but unfortunately, there is no inside class entry point to add methods nor attributes. I have opened an issue to add it, but I need a quick workaround.

I know I can use the typing library to forward declare the class I can localize in the *import entry point*:

```
import typing # cf https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/forward-declaration-in-python/
ConditionalRun = typing.NewType("ConditionalRun", AbstractConditional)
```

But I need to also forward define my methods. Is it possible?

As an ultimate workaround, I can edit the generated code, but it is not convenient.

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're asking about.